# Numbers SUMIF by dates within current week?

Tags: numbers

I have a table like this:

[image: First Column Dates, Last Column Amount Made that Day]

Which basically contains jobs I've done, the dates I did those jobs and how much that job made me.

I'd like to find out how much money I've made this week (current date is `09/10/2015`), with Monday being the first day of each week and Sunday the last. Monday of this week was on `05/10/2015`.

[image: circled week so far]

Above you can see the values I'd like to sum, because they were all jobs completed within this week.

I can't get anything closer than this:

[image: =SUMIF(Dates, TODAY(), Earnings)]

which only sums the money I've made today, but I want the whole week; how can I sum all the money I've made in this week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there may be other ways of doing this, but here is one.

To accomplish this dynamically (so that it changes when the current week changes), one can use the `WEEKNUM( )` function.

- Create a column (you can hide this later if you don't want it to show. See edit below) with the calculation of:

`WEEKNUM( A1 )` -- Where A1 is the first cell with a date.

- Drag this formula down the column.

Now you can use this formula in a cell to get the sum for the current week.

`SUMIF(Table 1::B,WEEKNUM(TODAY()),Table 1::C)`

This should give you the desired result.

See the screen shot.  The Function Inspector pane has more information on these functions.

---

[image: Numbers Formula]

---

**EDIT**

To hide a column:
 - Highlight the column
 - Click the disclosure arrow (or control click / right click)
 - Select **Hide Column**

To show again, right click in an adjacent column letter and select **Unhide**.

[image: Hide column dialog]

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that you could hide columns; how do you hide a column?

Comment: See my edit showing how to hide.